# How can I regulate the voltage from an USB port?

Tags: usb, voltage-regulator

I have a device plugged into the USB port of my car stereo. Occasionally, the device crashes, and I believe it is caused by power fluctuations in the USB port. I want to create a circuit that regulates the voltage between the USB port and the device that it's powering. I need to protect against power surges, and if possible, dips in the voltage. What kind of circuit would I need to create to accomplish this?

- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/316988/290114

  This answer is similar to what I'm looking for, if I use a 7805 regulator. The problem is that it sounds like the 7805 regulator requires a higher input voltage (maybe 7v) than the output voltage (5v) to operate correctly, but the input and output voltage will normally both be 5v. The answer also talks about using a polyswitch to cut off the power, but since I'm trying to keep my device from turning off, this would defeat the purpose.
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/107346/290114

  This answer sounds like it would be more suitable for my application because it suggests using an ADP1613 to regulate the voltage, which does not require a high input voltage. However, it looks like the device would be hard to work with, and I'm concerned that a USB port would not be able to handle the current that this might draw, especially a USB port in a car (although I could be wrong).

Note that there is always data being transferred between the device and the stereo, so it *must* be plugged into the USB port. This may also further complicate the problem.

Am I on the right track? I'd greatly appreciate any guidance you can provide. Sorry if the question seems elementary... hardware is not really my area.

Comment: The correct way to fix this is to fix the faulty USB port.

Comment: try placing a powered USB hub between the stereo and the device

Comment: Get a better cable.   They are not all created equal.

Comment: `I'm concerned that a USB port would not be able to handle the current that this might draw, especially a USB port in a car (although I could be wrong).` Probably. I don't know what device (i.e. type, brand/model, function, etc.) you are using but, the first thing I'd think about is the supply capability of the USB port: If the port is not capable of supplying enough power then the voltage may drop at, for example, peak loads.

Comment: "I believe it is caused by power fluctuations in the USB port" How did you come to that conclusion? Have you recorded the voltage dips with a scope? Can you post the pic?

Comment: @Lundin I attached a multimeter to the USB port. It read 5 volts for several minutes until the fuse eventually blew on the multimeter. Not sure if the fuse can blow from extended use or not, but if not, I assume this would indicate a power surge. I think the problem technically comes from my car itself (made in 2005), as the device only seems to crash when someone is in the passenger seat, weirdly. My current theory is that there is a short related to the pressure sensor in the passenger seat for the passenger airbag. The car has a history of weird electrical anomalies like that.

Comment: The fuse should not blow during voltage measurements - maybe you have connected it to the current measurement points? And additionally a multimeter reacts too slow to see anything useful; as the readings are averaged across a second or so. Therefore an oscilloscope is essential.

Comment: "*It read 5 volts for several minutes until the fuse eventually blew on the multimeter.*" It sounds like you were on current measurement range and short-circuited the 5 V supply with your meter. (Don't do that!) Usually there is no fuse in the voltage measurement range.

Comment: @JacobG. Well... at this point I'd politely advise you to hand over the problem to professionals. The fuse in a multimeter blows from a current rush when you have it set to measure current. The "power surges" you should be measuring are voltage surges. The fuse cannot blow if you measure voltage, nor from extended use. The fuse blowing is likely an indication of you short-circuiting something with the probes during measurement and not an indication of a problem in the car. There may now be a problem in the car which wasn't there when you started though...

Comment: There's no way the USB power on board a car would sag below 5V because it's fed by a >12V battery able to instantly deliver hundreds of amps. Similarly, there already needs to be a regulator turning >12V to 5V there, which should have no trouble getting rid of any spikes on the 12V side (that's what regulators are for). Please double-check your measurements, it's fairly likely you're dealing with something else than voltage fluctuations (likely just noise you need to filter out or crappy contacts you need to fix).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible your usb plug or socket, especially if cheap got oxidized over time and making a bad connection.

Simplest first is always the better, try to add a large cap (200-500uF) on the power lines of the USB and see if it keeps having issue.

Comment: Power glitches are very likely in cheap automotive environment. The OP likely has a substandard "car audio". A large cap might solve the issue, like this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/279583/117785